TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext') when creating new NextJs App
When creating a new nextjs application, getting the below error consistently on my new nextJs apps and on running my old nextjs apps on local even though the deployed version works fine.
I have tried downgrading but that didn't help a lot. Also tried to create a next app from scratch from the official documentation but still get the issue in new projects as well. First I thought its my project working, later I realised next is breaking.
Anyone facing this issue and know how to fix it?
 ✓ Ready in 1655ms
 ○ Compiling / ...
Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run:
  npx update-browserslist-db@latest
  Why you should do it regularly: https://github.com/browserslist/update-db#readme
 ✓ Compiled / in 3s (1261 modules)
 ⨯ TypeError: x is not a function
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
digest: "2745068690"
 ⨯ TypeError: x is not a function
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
digest: "2745068690"
TypeError: i is not a function
    at /Users/ashwajha/Desktop/boilerplate-saas/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:36:2976
    at e_ (/Users/ashwajha/Desktop/boilerplate-saas/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:263963)
    at e (/Users/ashwajha/Desktop/boilerplate-saas/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:268095)
    at eF (/Users/ashwajha/Desktop/boilerplate-saas/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:268583)
    at eq (/Users/ashwajha/Desktop/boilerplate-saas/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:274547)
    at ej (/Users/ashwajha/Desktop/boilerplate-saas/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:264791)
    at e_ (/Users/ashwajha/Desktop/boilerplate-saas/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:263833)
    at e (/Users/ashwajha/Desktop/boilerplate-saas/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:268095)
    at eF (/Users/ashwajha/Desktop/boilerplate-saas/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:268583)
    at /Users/ashwajha/Desktop/boilerplate-saas/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:265814
    at Array.toJSON (/Users/ashwajha/Desktop/boilerplate-saas/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:266278)
    at stringify (<anonymous>)
    at eq (/Users/ashwajha/Desktop/boilerplate-saas/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:274646)
    at eJ (/Users/ashwajha/Desktop/boilerplate-saas/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:275164)
    at Timeout._onTimeout (/Users/ashwajha/Desktop/boilerplate-saas/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:264951)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:569:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:512:7) {
  digest: '3402497221'
}
 ⨯ TypeError: i is not a function
    at stringify (<anonymous>)
digest: "3402497221"
 ⨯ TypeError: i is not a function
    at /Users/ashwajha/Desktop/boilerplate-saas/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:36:2976
    at e_ (/Users/ashwajha/Desktop/boilerplate-saas/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:263963)
    at e (/Users/ashwajha/Desktop/boilerplate-saas/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:268095)
    at eF (/Users/ashwajha/Desktop/boilerplate-saas/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:268583)
    at eq (/Users/ashwajha/Desktop/boilerplate-saas/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:274547)
    at ej (/Users/ashwajha/Desktop/boilerplate-saas/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:264791)
    at e_ (/Users/ashwajha/Desktop/boilerplate-saas/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:263833)
    at e (/Users/ashwajha/Desktop/boilerplate-saas/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:268095)
    at eF (/Users/ashwajha/Desktop/boilerplate-saas/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:268583)
    at /Users/ashwajha/Desktop/boilerplate-saas/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:265814
    at Array.toJSON (/Users/ashwajha/Desktop/boilerplate-saas/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:266278)
    at stringify (<anonymous>)
    at eq (/Users/ashwajha/Desktop/boilerplate-saas/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:274646)
    at eJ (/Users/ashwajha/Desktop/boilerplate-saas/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:275164)
    at Timeout._onTimeout (/Users/ashwajha/Desktop/boilerplate-saas/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:264951)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:569:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:512:7) {
  digest: '3402497221',
  page: '/'
}
 ○ Compiling /_error ...
 ✓ Compiled /_error in 1473ms (1409 modules)
 ⨯ TypeError: P(...).renderToReadableStream is not a function
    at e0 (/Users/ashwajha/Desktop/boilerplate-saas/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/pages.runtime.dev.js:8:21438)
    at Object.t [as renderPage] (/Users/ashwajha/Desktop/boilerplate-saas/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/pages.runtime.dev.js:26:920)
    at Object.defaultGetInitialProps (/Users/ashwajha/Desktop/boilerplate-saas/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/pages.runtime.dev.js:17:3550)
    at Document.getInitialProps (webpack-internal:///../../../../opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/next/dist/pages/_document.js:800:20)
    at V (/Users/ashwajha/Desktop/boilerplate-saas/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/pages.runtime.dev.js:8:5430)
    at n (/Users/ashwajha/Desktop/boilerplate-saas/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/pages.runtime.dev.js:26:1538)
    at e6 (/Users/ashwajha/Desktop/boilerplate-saas/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/pages.runtime.dev.js:26:2432)
    at /Users/ashwajha/Desktop/boilerplate-saas/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/pages.runtime.dev.js:26:2929
    at /Users/ashwajha/Desktop/boilerplate-saas/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/trace/tracer.js:140:36
    at NoopContextManager.with (/Users/ashwajha/Desktop/boilerplate-saas/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@opentelemetry/api/index.js:1:7062)
    at ContextAPI.with (/Users/ashwajha/Desktop/boilerplate-saas/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@opentelemetry/api/index.js:1:518)
    at NoopTracer.startActiveSpan (/Users/ashwajha/Desktop/boilerplate-saas/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@opentelemetry/api/index.js:1:18093)
    at ProxyTracer.startActiveSpan (/Users/ashwajha/Desktop/boilerplate-saas/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@opentelemetry/api/index.js:1:18854)
    at /Users/ashwajha/Desktop/boilerplate-saas/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/trace/tracer.js:122:103
    at NoopContextManager.with (/Users/ashwajha/Desktop/boilerplate-saas/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@opentelemetry/api/index.js:1:7062)
    at ContextAPI.with (/Users/ashwajha/Desktop/boilerplate-saas/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@opentelemetry/api/index.js:1:518)
    at NextTracerImpl.trace (/Users/ashwajha/Desktop/boilerplate-saas/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/trace/tracer.js:122:28)
    at e8 (/Users/ashwajha/Desktop/boilerplate-saas/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/pages.runtime.dev.js:26:2816)
    at async doRender (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:1381:30)
    at async cacheEntry.responseCache.get.routeKind (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:1555:28)
    at async DevServer.renderToResponseWithComponentsImpl (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:1463:28)
    at async DevServer.renderErrorToResponseImpl (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:2114:24)
    at async pipe.req.req (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:1988:30)
    at async DevServer.pipeImpl (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:911:25)
    at async NextNodeServer.handleCatchallRenderRequest (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js:286:21)
    at async DevServer.handleRequestImpl (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:807:17)
    at async /opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/next/dist/server/dev/next-dev-server.js:331:20
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/next/dist/trace/trace.js:151:20)
    at async DevServer.handleRequest (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/next/dist/server/dev/next-dev-server.js:328:24)
    at async invokeRender (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/router-server.js:163:21)
    at async handleRequest (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/router-server.js:342:24)
    at async requestHandlerImpl (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/router-server.js:366:13)
    at async Server.requestListener (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/start-server.js:140:13)
TypeError: e.renderToReadableStream is not a function
    at /Users/ashwajha/Desktop/boilerplate-saas/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/pages.runtime.dev.js:26:2111
    at NextTracerImpl.trace (/Users/ashwajha/Desktop/boilerplate-saas/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/trace/tracer.js:105:20)
    at /Users/ashwajha/Desktop/boilerplate-saas/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/pages.runtime.dev.js:26:2065
    at a (/Users/ashwajha/Desktop/boilerplate-saas/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/pages.runtime.dev.js:26:2140)
    at Object.t [as renderPage] (/Users/ashwajha/Desktop/boilerplate-saas/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/pages.runtime.dev.js:26:899)
    at Object.defaultGetInitialProps (/Users/ashwajha/Desktop/boilerplate-saas/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/pages.runtime.dev.js:17:3550)
    at Document.getInitialProps (webpack-internal:///../../../../opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/next/dist/pages/_document.js:800:20)
    at V (/Users/ashwajha/Desktop/boilerplate-saas/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/pages.runtime.dev.js:8:5430)
    at n (/Users/ashwajha/Desktop/boilerplate-saas/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/pages.runtime.dev.js:26:1538)
    at e6 (/Users/ashwajha/Desktop/boilerplate-saas/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/pages.runtime.dev.js:26:2432)
    at /Users/ashwajha/Desktop/boilerplate-saas/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/pages.runtime.dev.js:26:2929
    at /Users/ashwajha/Desktop/boilerplate-saas/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/trace/tracer.js:140:36
    at NoopContextManager.with (/Users/ashwajha/Desktop/boilerplate-saas/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@opentelemetry/api/index.js:1:7062)
    at ContextAPI.with (/Users/ashwajha/Desktop/boilerplate-saas/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@opentelemetry/api/index.js:1:518)
    at NoopTracer.startActiveSpan (/Users/ashwajha/Desktop/boilerplate-saas/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@opentelemetry/api/index.js:1:18093)
    at ProxyTracer.startActiveSpan (/Users/ashwajha/Desktop/boilerplate-saas/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@opentelemetry/api/index.js:1:18854)
    at /Users/ashwajha/Desktop/boilerplate-saas/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/trace/tracer.js:122:103
    at NoopContextManager.with (/Users/ashwajha/Desktop/boilerplate-saas/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@opentelemetry/api/index.js:1:7062)
    at ContextAPI.with (/Users/ashwajha/Desktop/boilerplate-saas/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@opentelemetry/api/index.js:1:518)
    at NextTracerImpl.trace (/Users/ashwajha/Desktop/boilerplate-saas/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/trace/tracer.js:122:28)
    at e8 (/Users/ashwajha/Desktop/boilerplate-saas/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/pages.runtime.dev.js:26:2816)
    at async doRender (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:1381:30)
    at async cacheEntry.responseCache.get.routeKind (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:1555:28)
    at async DevServer.renderToResponseWithComponentsImpl (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:1463:28)
    at async DevServer.renderErrorToResponseImpl (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:2114:24)
    at async pipe.req.req (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:1988:30)
    at async DevServer.pipeImpl (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:911:25)
    at async NextNodeServer.handleCatchallRenderRequest (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js:286:21)
    at async DevServer.handleRequestImpl (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:807:17)
    at async /opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/next/dist/server/dev/next-dev-server.js:331:20
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/next/dist/trace/trace.js:151:20)
    at async DevServer.handleRequest (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/next/dist/server/dev/next-dev-server.js:328:24)
    at async invokeRender (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/router-server.js:163:21)
    at async handleRequest (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/router-server.js:342:24)
    at async requestHandlerImpl (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/router-server.js:366:13)
    at async Server.requestListener (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/start-server.js:140:13)
TypeError: e.renderToReadableStream is not a function
    at /Users/ashwajha/Desktop/boilerplate-saas/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/pages.runtime.dev.js:26:2111
    at NextTracerImpl.trace (/Users/ashwajha/Desktop/boilerplate-saas/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/trace/tracer.js:105:20)
    at /Users/ashwajha/Desktop/boilerplate-saas/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/pages.runtime.dev.js:26:2065
    at a (/Users/ashwajha/Desktop/boilerplate-saas/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/pages.runtime.dev.js:26:2140)
    at Object.t [as renderPage] (/Users/ashwajha/Desktop/boilerplate-saas/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/pages.runtime.dev.js:26:899)
    at Object.defaultGetInitialProps (/Users/ashwajha/Desktop/boilerplate-saas/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/pages.runtime.dev.js:17:3550)
    at Document.getInitialProps (webpack-internal:///../../../../opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/next/dist/pages/_document.js:800:20)
    at V (/Users/ashwajha/Desktop/boilerplate-saas/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/pages.runtime.dev.js:8:5430)
    at n (/Users/ashwajha/Desktop/boilerplate-saas/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/pages.runtime.dev.js:26:1538)
    at e6 (/Users/ashwajha/Desktop/boilerplate-saas/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/pages.runtime.dev.js:26:2432)
    at /Users/ashwajha/Desktop/boilerplate-saas/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/pages.runtime.dev.js:26:2929
    at /Users/ashwajha/Desktop/boilerplate-saas/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/trace/tracer.js:140:36
    at NoopContextManager.with (/Users/ashwajha/Desktop/boilerplate-saas/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@opentelemetry/api/index.js:1:7062)
    at ContextAPI.with (/Users/ashwajha/Desktop/boilerplate-saas/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@opentelemetry/api/index.js:1:518)
    at NoopTracer.startActiveSpan (/Users/ashwajha/Desktop/boilerplate-saas/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@opentelemetry/api/index.js:1:18093)
    at ProxyTracer.startActiveSpan (/Users/ashwajha/Desktop/boilerplate-saas/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@opentelemetry/api/index.js:1:18854)
    at /Users/ashwajha/Desktop/boilerplate-saas/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/trace/tracer.js:122:103
    at NoopContextManager.with (/Users/ashwajha/Desktop/boilerplate-saas/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@opentelemetry/api/index.js:1:7062)
    at ContextAPI.with (/Users/ashwajha/Desktop/boilerplate-saas/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@opentelemetry/api/index.js:1:518)
    at NextTracerImpl.trace (/Users/ashwajha/Desktop/boilerplate-saas/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/trace/tracer.js:122:28)
    at e8 (/Users/ashwajha/Desktop/boilerplate-saas/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/pages.runtime.dev.js:26:2816)
    at async doRender (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:1381:30)
    at async cacheEntry.responseCache.get.routeKind (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:1555:28)
    at async DevServer.renderToResponseWithComponentsImpl (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:1463:28)
    at async DevServer.renderErrorToResponseImpl (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:2114:24)
    at async pipe.req.req (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:1988:30)
    at async DevServer.pipeImpl (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:911:25)
    at async NextNodeServer.handleCatchallRenderRequest (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js:286:21)
    at async DevServer.handleRequestImpl (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:807:17)
    at async /opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/next/dist/server/dev/next-dev-server.js:331:20
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/next/dist/trace/trace.js:151:20)
    at async DevServer.handleRequest (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/next/dist/server/dev/next-dev-server.js:328:24)
    at async invokeRender (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/router-server.js:163:21)
    at async handleRequest (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/router-server.js:342:24)
    at async requestHandlerImpl (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/router-server.js:366:13)
    at async Server.requestListener (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/start-server.js:140:13)
 ⨯ unhandledRejection: TypeError: e.renderToReadableStream is not a function
    at /Users/ashwajha/Desktop/boilerplate-saas/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/pages.runtime.dev.js:26:2111
    at NextTracerImpl.trace (/Users/ashwajha/Desktop/boilerplate-saas/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/trace/tracer.js:105:20)
    at /Users/ashwajha/Desktop/boilerplate-saas/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/pages.runtime.dev.js:26:2065
    at a (/Users/ashwajha/Desktop/boilerplate-saas/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/pages.runtime.dev.js:26:2140)
    at Object.t [as renderPage] (/Users/ashwajha/Desktop/boilerplate-saas/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/pages.runtime.dev.js:26:899)
    at Object.defaultGetInitialProps (/Users/ashwajha/Desktop/boilerplate-saas/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/pages.runtime.dev.js:17:3550)
    at Document.getInitialProps (webpack-internal:///../../../../opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/next/dist/pages/_document.js:800:20)
    at V (/Users/ashwajha/Desktop/boilerplate-saas/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/pages.runtime.dev.js:8:5430)
    at n (/Users/ashwajha/Desktop/boilerplate-saas/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/pages.runtime.dev.js:26:1538)
    at e6 (/Users/ashwajha/Desktop/boilerplate-saas/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/pages.runtime.dev.js:26:2432)
    at /Users/ashwajha/Desktop/boilerplate-saas/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/pages.runtime.dev.js:26:2929
    at /Users/ashwajha/Desktop/boilerplate-saas/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/trace/tracer.js:140:36
    at NoopContextManager.with (/Users/ashwajha/Desktop/boilerplate-saas/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@opentelemetry/api/index.js:1:7062)
    at ContextAPI.with (/Users/ashwajha/Desktop/boilerplate-saas/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@opentelemetry/api/index.js:1:518)
    at NoopTracer.startActiveSpan (/Users/ashwajha/Desktop/boilerplate-saas/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@opentelemetry/api/index.js:1:18093)
    at ProxyTracer.startActiveSpan (/Users/ashwajha/Desktop/boilerplate-saas/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@opentelemetry/api/index.js:1:18854)
    at /Users/ashwajha/Desktop/boilerplate-saas/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/trace/tracer.js:122:103
    at NoopContextManager.with (/Users/ashwajha/Desktop/boilerplate-saas/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@opentelemetry/api/index.js:1:7062)
    at ContextAPI.with (/Users/ashwajha/Desktop/boilerplate-saas/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@opentelemetry/api/index.js:1:518)
    at NextTracerImpl.trace (/Users/ashwajha/Desktop/boilerplate-saas/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/trace/tracer.js:122:28)
    at e8 (/Users/ashwajha/Desktop/boilerplate-saas/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/pages.runtime.dev.js:26:2816)
    at async doRender (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:1381:30)
    at async cacheEntry.responseCache.get.routeKind (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:1555:28)
    at async DevServer.renderToResponseWithComponentsImpl (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:1463:28)
    at async DevServer.renderErrorToResponseImpl (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:2114:24)
    at async pipe.req.req (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:1988:30)
    at async DevServer.pipeImpl (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:911:25)
    at async NextNodeServer.handleCatchallRenderRequest (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js:286:21)
    at async DevServer.handleRequestImpl (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:807:17)
    at async /opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/next/dist/server/dev/next-dev-server.js:331:20
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/next/dist/trace/trace.js:151:20)
    at async DevServer.handleRequest (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/next/dist/server/dev/next-dev-server.js:328:24)
    at async invokeRender (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/router-server.js:163:21)
    at async handleRequest (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/router-server.js:342:24)
    at async requestHandlerImpl (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/router-server.js:366:13)
    at async Server.requestListener (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/start-server.js:140:13)
 ⨯ unhandledRejection: TypeError: e.renderToReadableStream is not a function
    at /Users/ashwajha/Desktop/boilerplate-saas/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/pages.runtime.dev.js:26:2111
    at NextTracerImpl.trace (/Users/ashwajha/Desktop/boilerplate-saas/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/trace/tracer.js:105:20)
    at /Users/ashwajha/Desktop/boilerplate-saas/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/pages.runtime.dev.js:26:2065
    at a (/Users/ashwajha/Desktop/boilerplate-saas/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/pages.runtime.dev.js:26:2140)
    at Object.t [as renderPage] (/Users/ashwajha/Desktop/boilerplate-saas/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/pages.runtime.dev.js:26:899)
    at Object.defaultGetInitialProps (/Users/ashwajha/Desktop/boilerplate-saas/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/pages.runtime.dev.js:17:3550)
    at Document.getInitialProps (webpack-internal:///../../../../opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/next/dist/pages/_document.js:800:20)
    at V (/Users/ashwajha/Desktop/boilerplate-saas/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/pages.runtime.dev.js:8:5430)
    at n (/Users/ashwajha/Desktop/boilerplate-saas/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/pages.runtime.dev.js:26:1538)
    at e6 (/Users/ashwajha/Desktop/boilerplate-saas/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/pages.runtime.dev.js:26:2432)
    at /Users/ashwajha/Desktop/boilerplate-saas/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/pages.runtime.dev.js:26:2929
    at /Users/ashwajha/Desktop/boilerplate-saas/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/trace/tracer.js:140:36
    at NoopContextManager.with (/Users/ashwajha/Desktop/boilerplate-saas/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@opentelemetry/api/index.js:1:7062)
    at ContextAPI.with (/Users/ashwajha/Desktop/boilerplate-saas/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@opentelemetry/api/index.js:1:518)
    at NoopTracer.startActiveSpan (/Users/ashwajha/Desktop/boilerplate-saas/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@opentelemetry/api/index.js:1:18093)
    at ProxyTracer.startActiveSpan (/Users/ashwajha/Desktop/boilerplate-saas/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@opentelemetry/api/index.js:1:18854)
    at /Users/ashwajha/Desktop/boilerplate-saas/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/trace/tracer.js:122:103
    at NoopContextManager.with (/Users/ashwajha/Desktop/boilerplate-saas/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@opentelemetry/api/index.js:1:7062)
    at ContextAPI.with (/Users/ashwajha/Desktop/boilerplate-saas/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@opentelemetry/api/index.js:1:518)
    at NextTracerImpl.trace (/Users/ashwajha/Desktop/boilerplate-saas/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/trace/tracer.js:122:28)
    at e8 (/Users/ashwajha/Desktop/boilerplate-saas/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/pages.runtime.dev.js:26:2816)
    at async doRender (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:1381:30)
    at async cacheEntry.responseCache.get.routeKind (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:1555:28)
    at async DevServer.renderToResponseWithComponentsImpl (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:1463:28)
    at async DevServer.renderErrorToResponseImpl (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:2114:24)
    at async pipe.req.req (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:1988:30)
    at async DevServer.pipeImpl (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:911:25)
    at async NextNodeServer.handleCatchallRenderRequest (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js:286:21)
    at async DevServer.handleRequestImpl (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:807:17)
    at async /opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/next/dist/server/dev/next-dev-server.js:331:20
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/next/dist/trace/trace.js:151:20)
    at async DevServer.handleRequest (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/next/dist/server/dev/next-dev-server.js:328:24)
    at async invokeRender (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/router-server.js:163:21)
    at async handleRequest (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/router-server.js:342:24)
    at async requestHandlerImpl (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/router-server.js:366:13)
    at async Server.requestListener (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/start-server.js:140:13)


